# How do I force SSL on Craft?

Tags: htaccess

I've installed a ssl cert on a site and it's working. Now I want to redirect visitors coming in on http over to https

I've put this code and only this code in the htaccess file, but it's causing a redirect loop.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [R,L]

</IfModule>
```

My original htaccess looked like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Could Craft somehow be causing the redirect loop?

In the Craft CP I have the Site URL set to https://www.mysite.com

Comment: This may be useful for you, though it's aimed at the control panel rather than the site as a whole: http://craftcookbook.net/recipes/181

Comment: Thanks. Tried that and this (http://buildwithcraft.com/help/force-ssl), both send admin into a redirect loop.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For reference, this worked:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: This still causes an `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` for me

Comment: This worked for a while for me, but now it causes `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Answer (score 15):

I recommend trying out the Patrol plugin.  It avoids .htaccess headbanging and just handles the redirects via PHP.

[Patrol Plugin for Craft CMS](https://github.com/selvinortiz/craft.patrol)

In the Settings, turn on `Secure Connections` and add a backslash `/` to the *Protected Areas* settings box.  That will force SSL across the board.  If you want to get more specific, you can provide multiple, more-specific paths.

Comment: The settings changed. Now you need to put `'patrol' => ['forceSsl' => true, 'restrictedAreas' => ['/']]` in `craft/config/general.php`

Answer (score 6):

Try this sample htaccess-file I'm using on another site.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not secure
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# Redirect to the secure version
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Normal redirect rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks. Even with just that code in the htaccess, I'm still getting a redirect loop.

Comment: I edited my answer with a complete code. Can you try that one?

Answer (score 1):

Because I have so little reputation I cannot comment or like anything.

But @[naboovalley](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4129/5557) 's answer did the trick for me! all the other ones gave me

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS!

So the right answer to this question is probably:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not secure
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
# Redirect to the secure version
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Normal redirect rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Thank you @[naboovalley](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4129/5557)!

Answer (score 1):

I had to adapt the above slightly to play nicely. Hopefully this saves someone some head banging.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 # If the request is not secure
 RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
 # Redirect to the secure version
 RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

 # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```